# JavaFx: TableViewSkin initialization

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I am implementing custom `TableView` elements like custom `ContextMenu` as tableMenu. To achieve this I need to get an instance of `TableHeaderRow` but I got problems here. In the `initialize()` method the `TableView#getSkin()` is null. But I am wondering why? When is the `Skin` initialized? To get a temporal solution I am using `Platform.runLater()` but it is not working every time as expected. As I remember @kleopatra mentioned in a comment, that you cannot be sure `runLater()` is executed at the expected time.

This causes sometimes that the custom ContextMenu is not rendered correctly.

This is how my `Controller` class looks like:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<?> tableView;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        // null
        System.out.println(tableView.getSkin());

        // most of the time not null. but it happens to be null
        Platform.runLater(() -> System.out.println(tableView.getSkin()));

        // here getTableHeader returns null
        applyCustomTableMenu(getTableHeader(tableView));

        // here getTableHeader sometimes returns the nonnull reference
        Platform.runLater(() -> applyCustomTableMenu(getTableHeader(tableView)));
    }

    private TableHeaderRow getTableHeader(TableView<?> tableView) {
        return (TableHeaderRow) tableView.queryAccessibleAttribute(AccessibleAttribute.HEADER);
    }

    private void applyCustomTableMenu(TableHeaderRow tableHeaderRow) {
        // implementation
        System.out.println(tableHeaderRow);
    }

}
```

Where is the point when I can be sure that the skin is initialized and I can get a non null reference to my `TableHeaderRow` ?

I would also accept any suggestion which would provide me every time a non null reference to my `TableHeaderRow`.

Comment: the skin is created when a control is added to the scenegraph. It's a property, so you can register  a listener to `control.skinProperty().addListener( .. if (newSkin != null) { doStuff(); unregisterMe()})`

Comment: btw, nice trick to access it via accessibleAttribute - my learn item of theday :))

Comment: Hmm...yeah I think I'll use a listener, but it is strange there is no way to know when everything is initialized...

Comment: don't understand the "no way to know when" - the exact time is either after instantiation of the control (if the control sets its skin in the constructor, which is not recommened but might happen) or when the listener notifies you :)

Comment: Okay, but I mean the whole UI initialization. The point is on **everything** .There are still uninitialized nodes even if the skin is not null. For example the `tableHeaderRow.getColumnHeaderFor(column)` returns null.

Comment: yeah, the column headers are lazyly created during a layout pass ;) Don't like that because it introduces undefined states .. but that's a way of coding the fx implementars seem to love ... you have to listen to the columnHeaders (recursively) if you want to be certain they are created. On the darker side: getColumnHeadersFor is unaccessible in fx9+ <g>

Comment: Pretty much everything that can be lazily created in JavaFX _is_ lazily created. However, everything that needs to be created should be created by the time the `Window` is shown. Maybe you can use this? Note that the `scene` property (of the `TableView`) will be null inside the `initialize` method as well. You'll have to listen to the `scene` property, then the `Scene`'s `window` property, and then for the `Window` to be shown.